# Draggable tabs in jQuery Tabs control

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a jQuery UI tabs control, whose tabs can be dragged around, I would like to suppress this behaviour but not sure where to start. What css parameters shall I look at in order to disable drag'n'drop in my tabs?

I get a: Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'
When trying this: `$(thisTab).draggable('disable')`

Comment: It should be something like $(".ui-tabs-nav").sortable("disable"); Please post some code if you need more precise answer.

Comment: by default the tabs aren't sortable, so you should check where you made them sortable.

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing me in the right direction